# ASP ListView to Winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, listview, user-interface

ASP ListView can be easily made to change the view of item on lick, like display a table but when the item is clicked expand it and show details in some custom format that differs from table. (e.g. some multiline text)
Have anyone seen any free control, or a tutorial to make one with similar behavior but for winforms?

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search found this: http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview.

I'm sure a further search would reveal more at various budgets and functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking about free ones.